# CSS mode won't indent values across multiple lines

Tags: indentation, formatting, css

When a line in my CSS file appears to be too long (typically a property followed by a bunch of values), I want to split them in to several new lines like this:

[image: What I dream of]

But I have to manually enter spaces before the lines to achieve that. In reality, when I hit TAB with my cursor on the `url` line, what I get is this:

[image: What I actually get]

The worst thing is that, after manually inserting the spaces, when I hit TAB again on the same line, it goes back to the ugly format.

This is not a significant issue but it really pains me and I really hope we can have a decent solution here. Thanks in advance!

M-x version:

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0, NS appkit-1504.60 Version 10.12.1 (Build 16B2555)) of 2016-11-27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert below code into your emacs setup:

```
(defadvice smie-indent-line (after smie-indent-line-after-hack activate)
  "Customize your own css coding style."
  (if (eq major-mode 'css-mode)
      (let* ((cur-line (buffer-substring-no-properties
                        (line-beginning-position)
                        (line-end-position))))
        (if (string-match "^\\( +\\)url" cur-line)
            (let* ((empty-spaces (match-string 1 cur-line)))
              (replace-regexp empty-spaces
                              (make-string (+ (length empty-spaces) css-indent-offset) 32)
                              nil
                              (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))))))
```

My code is copied from http://blog.binchen.org/posts/indent-jsx-in-emacs.html with a little modification.

I will show you how to solve similar problems for other languages:

- Learn Emacs lisp
- Press `C-h k ENTER` and read documentation. In my case, it's documentation of `newline-and-indent`. It says "Indentation is done using the value of `indent-line-function'."
- Press `C-h v indent-line-function`. Now you know you need hack `smie-indent-line`
- Done

Answer (score 1):

I just committed a [fix](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=d2d6e4452c8f2cf571f2d866b248131b3ef31c3a) to CSS mode, so it should hopefully work as you describe out of the box in the next Emacs release. (Or you could always fetch the [latest version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el) from the master branch if you don't want to wait for a release.)

Comment: I've tested the new version and it works perfectly. Thanks! (Though I'm experiencing issues with displaying RGB colours inside css-mode...)

Comment: Yeah, the new indent part is awesome, but the just-added colour displaying thing doesn't work right, so I guess I will simply add your commit to the original `css-mode.el`.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. Could you submit a bug report with `M-x report-emacs-bug` and describe there the problems you're experiencing with the new colorization feature? (You should be able to turn it off by setting `css-fontify-colors` to `nil`, by the way.)